# Configure webpack proxy for http requests in VueJs + Axios

Tags: webpack, vue.js, proxy

I'm creating a simple VueJs application with Axios being used to make http requests. Something like this:

```
load () {
  let vm = this
  this.$http
    .get('/api/posts')
    .then(response => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // failure
    })
}
```

And in the webpack configuration file, `config/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
dev: {
 proxyTable: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
  }
},
}
```

Is there anything missing to make this work? According to this [documentation](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html), webpack uses `http-proxy-middleware`, but I'm not sure it's already somehow built-in with vue-cli project generation, or we need to install it manually. Neither the generated template nor any tutorials mentioned this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of vue-cli are you using? 2 or 3 (beta)?

Comment: the latest, `2.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your `proxyTable` configuration per se. But...

Double check your `config/index.js` file. If you added that `proxyTable` snippet to the a config file with the default content, your `config/index.js` file will be:

```js
module.exports = {
  dev: {
    proxyTable: {                                          // the snippet you added
      '/api': {                                            // the snippet you added
        target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',     // the snippet you added
        secure: false,                                     // the snippet you added
        changeOrigin: true,                                // the snippet you added
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }                       // the snippet you added
      }                                                    // the snippet you added
    },                                                     // the snippet you added

    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},                  // <================================ oops...

    // Various Dev Server settings
    host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
    ...
```

Now, notice there is a `proxyTable: {},` property there. It is overwriting your configuration.

**Solution:** Remove `proxyTable: {},`.

Comment: well, what I did in fact was to fill `proxyTable: {}` that was already there, as you pointed out, so this should not be the case.

Comment: Check if there's no other `proxyTable`. Or maybe post your whole config file, because th at snippet had no problem (just tested it).